# How to query using a list o id's in where parameter

Tags: postgresql

I have a query:

```
select * from table
where id = 10
```

Now I have a list with 300 id's and I want to use the query above to query these 300 id's in the where clause concatenating the results.

How can I do this in Postgresql V14?

Comment: `where id IN (....)`

Comment: where id =ANY('{1,2,3,4}')